# How to omit the header in when use spark to read csv.file?

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to use Spark to read a csv file in jupyter notebook. So far I have

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[4]").getOrCreate()
reviews_df = spark.read.option("header","true").csv("small.csv")
reviews_df.collect()
```

This is how the `reviews_df` looks like:

```
[Row(reviewerID=u'A1YKOIHKQHB58W', asin=u'B0001VL0K2', overall=u'5'),
 Row(reviewerID=u'A2YB0B3QOHEFR', asin=u'B000JJSRNY', overall=u'5'),
 Row(reviewerID=u'AAI0092FR8V1W', asin=u'B0060MYKYY', overall=u'5'),
 Row(reviewerID=u'A2TAPSNKK9AFSQ', asin=u'6303187218', overall=u'5'),
 Row(reviewerID=u'A316JR2TQLQT5F', asin=u'6305364206', overall=u'5')...]
```

But each row of the data frame contains the column names, how can I reformat the data, so that it can become:

```
 [(u'A1YKOIHKQHB58W', u'B0001VL0K2', u'5'), 
  (u'A2YB0B3QOHEFR', u'B000JJSRNY', u'5')....]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dataframe always returns `Row` objects, thats why when you issue `collect()` on dataframe, it shows -

```
Row(reviewerID=u'A1YKOIHKQHB58W', asin=u'B0001VL0K2', overall=u'5')
```

to get what you want, you can do -

```
reviews_df.rdd.map(lambda row : (row.reviewerID,row.asin,row.overall)).collect()
```

this will return you `tuple of values of rows`